# How to embed variable with blade code into blade template?

Tags: html, laravel, image, email, laravel-blade

I am new in Laravel.
I'm trying to send emails with inline images.
I have a blade template, but the part with the images is dynamic and comes from the front end.

This is the part of the blade template where the data from the front end renders:

```
 <div style="font-family:open sans,helvetica neue,helvetica,arial,sans-serif">
     {!! $details['body'] !!}
 </div>
```

The $details['body'] variable was pure html. But the images were not showing in the emails because they were in base64. So, if I do $message->embed directly in the blade, it works and the emails show the images well:

```
<p><img src="{{ $message->embed('data:image/jpeg;base64,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') }}">Hola</p>
```

But when the same comes in $details['body'], the emails arrive with the img tag empty.

So, it is a problem of how to embed the variable with the blade code into the blade. The blade code would be {{ $message->embed(.....) }}

Please I need your help

I tried saving the images in storage

Comment: Blade doesn't work like this; Blade is compiled down to PHP which is then executed, echoing a string isn't going to compile it to PHP then execute it (`eval`uate it) ... what was the issue with having the image in storage?

Comment: I honestly did not understand what the issue is

Comment: @lagbox the issue was how to access to the storage path?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I have a variable with blade syntax that i'm passing to a blade. But the blade won't read that blade syntax

Comment: what do you mean? what is the output?

Comment: @matiaslauriti so for example, the variable that I am sending to the blade contains this string "<p>Hi <img src="{{ $message->embed('data:image/jpeg;ba......."}}></p> "
In the blade I use the variable like this {!! $variable['body'] !!}
And when I send emails with this blade and then inspect the mail, the img tag is empty and I can't see the image: <img>

What I need to do is to send emails with inline images, and the front end is the one who creates the html and passes it to the back end as an string, so I need some idea of how to do it

Comment: Oh, I see, the issue is that you have that HTML inside a variable, but that string has `{{ $message->xxxxx }}` and it is not being rendered or processed, right? If that is the case, it will never work, that is not how Blade works. You must already have processed the string, it will never do Blade inside Blade (string with blade, processed by blade)

Comment: @matiaslauriti right! it is the issue

Comment: @matiaslauriti which could be a way to include inline images in the blade? Please guide me

Comment: You have to process the content before you put it in the variable. Ideally it would be done in the controller

Comment: @matiaslauriti I don't know how, help me figure out

Answer (score 0):

So my solution is this, but I am open to better ideas.

I receive the variable body as an array of html parts but when an image comes, it is just img:

```
"body": [
   "<p>Text",
   "img",
   "</p>",
   "<p>more text</p>",
   "img"
]
```

This also can be done spliting the HTML. What is important here is to know the order of the elements. I also receive an array of the images in base64:

```
 "images":[
     "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j...",
     "data...."
 ]
```

Then in the blade, I loop through the body and if it is img, I embed the image of the images array according to the index i which increments in one every time there is an img:

```
 @php                                                                                       
    $i = 0;                                                                                    
 @endphp

                                                                                        
 @foreach ($details['body'] as $element)                                                                                        
    @if ($element == "img")                                                                                              
        <img src="{{ $message->embed($details['images'][$i]) }}">                                                                                            
                                                                                                
        @php                                                                                            
             $i++;                                                                                                
        @endphp
                                                                                            
     @else                                                                                              
         {!! $element !!}                                                                                            
     @endif                                                                                     
 @endforeach
```